# getting index/row num of active cell from array with multiple rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find the `index` of a value in an array. The array is a spreadsheet, and I want to search down the rows till it finds the value in the `active cell` and returns the row number/index.

I have tried this searching across columns and it works fine, but when trying to search down rows it does something I can't quite figure out.

```
var datass =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('####')
var actCell = ss.getActiveCell()

var name =datass.getRange(3,2,datass.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var nameIndex = name[0].indexOf(actCell.getValue)
```

`nameIndex` always returns -1 unless `name[#]`is the right index number. even if I omit a # it returns -1.

`logger.log(name)` shows that the pulled is corrected but because of the way it pulls the data index only searches on []

it shows as:

```
[[##], [##], [##]]
```

when this functions correctly searching along columns instead of rows, the log shows as

```
[##,##,##,##]
```

how do can I search down my list and get the row number based off the value in my active cell?

Comment: Try using [textFinder]((https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#createTextFinder(String))

Answer (score 0):

### (Option 1)

As what was mentioned by @Cooper, you can use [Range.createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#createtextfinderfindtext) to search for a specific string within your selected range.

---

### (Option 2)

You can convert your 2-d array to 1-d array to be able to search for a specific value using [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

**Sample Code:**

```
  var datass =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet15");
  var actCell = datass.getActiveCell();
  var rowStart = 3;
  var name =datass.getRange(rowStart,2,datass.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues().flat();
  Logger.log(name);
  Logger.log(actCell.getA1Notation());
  Logger.log(actCell.getValue());
  var nameIndex = name.indexOf(actCell.getValue());
  Logger.log("match found at row: "+(rowStart+nameIndex));
```

**What it does?**

1. Select a sheet and get its active cell.
2. Get the values of a given range. This will return a 2-d array values. Convert it to 1-d array using [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Your array will be from this `[[##], [##], [##]]` to `[##,##,##]`
3. Use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to search for a value within the array.

**Note:**

- When you select the range of values, you start at `row3`. To get the actual row index of the matched value you also need to add an offset 3 to the index found in your `name` array

**Output:**

[image]

```
4:59:23 AM  Notice  Execution started
4:59:24 AM  Info    [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
4:59:24 AM  Info    A1
4:59:24 AM  Info    D
4:59:24 AM  Info    match found at row: 6
4:59:24 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```